# Minehut lobby fps low

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

Whenever I join the main minehut lobby I get a considerable drop of fps. The frames I get range from 10-30. I also know that my settings are fine because when I join hypixel my frames are above 500.
my GPU is rtx2060
my CPU is ryzen 5.
So if it's not my pc or my internet why am I getting low fps in this one server?

Comment: Check how many entities there are via `F3`

Comment: ooooh.... thats a lot.... a LOT

Comment: thats probably why :)

Comment: yep i guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting a low FPS because of the amount of entities. A high number of entities will always increase lag. You may not be able to fix this unless Minehut has different lobbies. If it does have different lobbies you could try to go in a lobby with a small amount of people, which should decrease lag.